# this.props.match.params.id in React.js is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the id from the URL therefore I can use this id to get and output the user info but I can't get id from URL. I've seen useParams() but I think it is not applicable with class component. May I know if there is an alternative solution for this?

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    const stud_id = this.props.match.params.id;
    console.log(stud_id);
 }
```

[see error message from console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NfwO.png)

Comment: this.props.match is undefined. Try finding why. You can stop the error by using this.props.match?.params?.id

Comment: use console.log(this.props); to find your issue

Comment: Make sure you are exporting the class component as a wrapped  component with `withRouter`

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of reading URL params in React is using React Router. In React Router, you get URL params with `this.props.match.params` like you are trying to, but you have to call your component inside a `Route`, like for example:

```js
<Route 
  path="/:id" 
  component={YourComponent} 
/>
```

instead of just

```js
<YourComponent />
```

So that your component receives the `match` prop and can access `this.props.match.params.id`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using

```
<Route path="/blah" component={()=><YourComponent someProp={someProp}>}/>
```

I mean, with arrow function as it child component, you have to pass the pros of the father (Route) to the child (YourComponent) like that:

```
<Route path="/blah" component={({match})=><YourComponent match={match} someProp={someProp}>}/>
```

Because you're creating a new "generation" so you have to pass the props by your self